# Calculate integral with special rectangle

Tags: calculus, integration

Can you guys help me with this integral:

$\int_0^2 \int_{y/2}^{(y+4)/2} y^2(2x-y)^2e^{(2x-y)^3} dx dy,$

There is a hint: transform the integration-area into a rectangle.

I don't understand the hint. Should i switch the integrals?

Answer (score 1):

The region of integration is a parallelogram, with corners $(y, x) = (0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)$. The hint is to perform a substitution which will make that parallelogram into a rectangle.

The substitution which takes that parallelogram to the rectangle with corners $(u, v) = (0,0), (2,2)$ is $(u, v) = (y, x-\frac{y}{2})$. This can be performed without touching the $y$ variable at all:

$$\int_{y=0}^2 \int_{x=y/2}^{y/2+2} y^2 (2x-y)^2 e^{(2x-y)^3} dx dy = \int_{y=0}^2 \int_{v=0}^2 y^2 (2v)^2 e^{(2v)^3}dv dy$$
where the Jacobian for the substitution is readily seen to be $1$ by brute computation, or by the fact that we have performed a shear in the 2D plane which does not alter area.

This integral is separable: $$\int_0^2 y^2 dy \int_0^2 \underbrace{(2v)^2 e^{(2v)^3}}_{\dfrac{d}{dv} \frac{1}{6} e^{(2v)^3}} dv$$

Comment: No. It is between $y=0, y=2, x=y/2, x=(y+4)/2$.

Comment: okay thank you,whats up with that substitution. I dont get it how do you find a substitution?

Comment: The manipulation of regions by substitution should be covered in whatever source you found the integral.

Comment: what do you mean with source you find the integral?

Comment: What resource are you using to learn integration?

Comment: Calculus a complete course from adams. I have to find a substitution with u(x,y) and v(x,y)

Comment: Then what I meant was "The manipulation of regions by substitution should be covered in Adams's Calculus: a Complete Course". It ought to contain examples where regions are transformed into each other to make integration easier, if it's well-written.

Comment: Yeah i can see that they transform areas but don't know how they do it. Can you explain it?

Comment: A substitution is nothing more nor less than a transformation of the region of integration and a corresponding transformation of the integrand. I don't have any better way to explain it than "transformations transform things" :P

Comment: Can you just tell me what the integral is,  i have  to calculate?

Comment: I have edited it in.